# How to run a protractor tests with different input parameters

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor

I am testing an angular application and I would like to feed my search tests with different parameters and run the test for all parameters.
In my case I have a search test:

```
require("./myconfig.js");

describe('change number of items displayed by page', function () {

var loginPage = require("./Pages/login-page.js");
var searchPage = require("./Pages/search-page.js");
var ptor;
ptor = protractor.getInstance();

it('should display 20 items per page', function () {


    searchPage.home.click();
    searchPage.searchTxt.sendKeys(Parameter);
    searchPage.searchBtn.click();
    var result = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('object in objects'));
    result.then(function (arr) {
        expect(arr.length).toEqual(20);
    });


}, 50000);


});
```

is there a way using Jasmine and protractor to call parmaeter from an XML file? Tahnks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try xml2js xml parser in Node and use in your test.

```
    > npm install xml2js
```